# MVC3 date validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/

I tried to make the sample from the above link work, but cant get it correct. I am not sure what is it i am doing wrong?

I copied the Model validation

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Start Date of Construction")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayNameAttribute("End Date of Construction")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DateGreaterThan("StartDate", "Estimated end date of construction must be greater than the start date of the construction")]
public DateTime? EndDateOf { get; set; }
```

Followed by DateGreaterThan code.

in View

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
```

But nothing fires in the button click, if anyone can shed some light.It would be really helpful or even any other different way of doing it is appreciated.Similarly trying to get a validation work from Model when selecting a value in the drop down and value entered in text box.

Comment: Can we see your controller code where you are posting the form data back to?

Comment: the source code for the example you are following is downloadable from [here](https://github.com/vgheri/DateCustomValidationExample). Download it and compare with what you have tried, that way you will be able to find a solution faster and more importantly you will be happy to figure out the problem yourself. Believe me !

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of `[DisplayName("Start Date of Construction")]` should use `[Display(Name="Start Date of Construction")]`
2. Instead of `[DisplayNameAttribute("End Date of Construction")]` should use `[Display(Name="End Date of Construction")]`

See if you get at least this running. Your data annotation attributes are messed up, just look for samples on the web.

Comment: Please let me know if this was of any help! Thanks.